# Pandas df iteration looking for duplicates

Tags: python, pandas, iteration

I need some help with some pandas code to iterate a pandas data frame looking back 3 days and forward 3 days relevant to a date in the particular row.

I've tried a number of ways to attack this problem and believe I'm close.

When I run the line of code outside the loop, I get True or false, which is what I'm expecting, but it is only relevant to one date.

Here is the code for my loop:

```
for ind, row in df.iterrows():
    start = row.Day-pd.Timedelta(days=3)
    end = row.Day+pd.Timedelta(days=3)
    row['FCR'] = row[(row['Day'] >= start) & (row['Day'] <= end)].duplicated(subset='Source (A Number)')
```

Here is a line of data from excel that I'm reading; note in Pandas I have converted Day into datetime.  The data I am working with is millions of rows.

> Row,Day,Application,Channel,Start Time,End Time,Source (A Number)  
>   1,2019-01-01,ContactCenter,CallIn,1/1/19,1/1/19,+6100297096500

I'm trying to create a new column called 'FCR' and this is is either true or false depending on if there were duplicated records in the last 3 days or future 3 days.

Here is a sample of data:

```
+-----+------------+-------------------+
| Row |    Day     | Source (A Number) |
+-----+------------+-------------------+
|   1 | 2019-01-01 | +6100295096511    |
|   2 | 2019-01-02 | +61470345116      |
|   3 | 2019-01-03 | +61438668819      |
|   4 | 2019-01-04 | +64211031448      |
|   5 | 2019-01-05 | +6100265424300    |
|   6 | 2019-01-06 | +61352571193      |
|   7 | 2019-01-07 | +64220697434      |
|   8 | 2019-01-08 | +61438668819      |
|   9 | 2019-01-09 | +6100246972177    |
|  10 | 2019-01-10 | +6100242330110    |
|  11 | 2019-01-11 | +61438826418      |
+-----+------------+-------------------+
```

Help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I cannot test it without a sample of your data, but I think the following should do the job.

Define a custom function which does the 3-days selection and checks for duplicates. It should return a single boolean value.
Then you can use [apply](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html) to use it on each row of your dataframe and obtain the value to be added in your new column.

Now is not clear to me if you want to check if there is *any* duplicate in the time window, or if there are duplicates of the current row only, so I propose you two versions of `checkdupes`.

This one checks for *any* duplicate in the time window:

```
def checkdupes(data, x):
    start = x['Day'] - pd.Timedelta(days=3)
    end = x['Day'] + pd.Timedelta(days=3)
    return data.loc[(data['Day'] >= start) & (data['Day'] <= end)].duplicated(subset='Source (A Number)').any()
```

This one checks only for duplicates of current row (the central value of the time window):

```
def checkdupes(data, x):
    start = x['Day'] - pd.Timedelta(days=3)
    end = x['Day'] + pd.Timedelta(days=3)
    correspondences = data.loc[(data['Day'] >= start) & (data['Day'] <= end)]['Source (A Number)'].isin([x['Source (A Number)']])
    return correspondences.sum() > 1
```

Pick the function you need and use it in this way with `apply`:

```
df['FCR'] = df.apply(lambda r : checkdupes(df, r), axis=1)
```

Comment: Thank you for your response, I am still getting an error and have added it to another 'answer'  below

Comment: Please, edit your original question in case, but do not use answers as replies. On stackoverflow answers should provide a solution to the question. In any case I think I got where is the error, let me fix my answer

Comment: @Ianh answer fixed, try now

Comment: thanks for your response.  The code is still producing an error the same as prior; KeyError: (True, 'occurred at index 0').

Comment: Also, the condition I am testing is checking for any duplicate within the time window.

Comment: Can you [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/56510756/edit) your question and provide a sample of your data? I think the snippet I provided should work, if there is an error I cannot help you without testing against some data.

Comment: Sample of data added.  I have provided 11 rows, but in actual fact, the dataset is millions of rows long.

Comment: Sorry, the condition I need is actually - the one checks only for duplicates of the current row (the central value of the time window)

Comment: @Ianh ok, fixed. Now should work. Turns out it was a silly error from me, but I didn't notice. That's why is always good to provide a sample data!